# C programming secure function

Tags: c, eclipse, api, c++14

Please suggest any changes to execute the following program.

This is following I have tried for concatenating  but it was printing only dest string. Not concatenated string.

```
 #include <stdio.h> 
 #include <string.h> 
 #include"safe_str_lib.h"

 int main () {
  char src[50], dest[50];
  char max=8; char Len=8  
  strcpy(src,  "This is source");   
  strcpy(dest, "This is destination");
  //strncat(dest, src, 15);
  strncat_s(dest,7,src,8);
  printf("Final destination string : |%s|", dest);
  return(0);
 }
```

Comment: For starters, your code wont compile with missing semi colons and closing braces. Perhaps you should revise your code and get it to the point it's a readable, [minimal and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your code is working correctly.  that's because in your strncat_s you are setting a maximal length of 7 on the dest.

Comment: You write "implement" but it seems you ask about how to **use** it. Could you clarify?

Comment: I haven't heard of `strncat_s` before. Is it C, C++ or both?